# Vectors: Find all values of a and b such that $(1,2,a)$ and $(2,(1-b),3)$ are perpendicular

Tags: vectors

I know that, for the vectors to be perpendicular, their cross product must equal $0$.
i.e. $w = u \times v$, where $u = (1,2,a)$ and $v = (2,(1-b),3)$

From that, I got $w = ( (6-a+ab), (-3+2a), (-b-3) )$

When checking, $w \cdot u$ and $w \cdot v$ must equal $0$

This does occur, but I am no closer to finding what $a$ and $b$ are

Comment: Note: **Dot / scalar product** must be zero for perpendicular vectors...

Comment: While what you are saying about $ \ \vec{w} \ $ is true, you'll find setting $ \ \vec{u} \ \cdot \ \vec{v} \ = \ 0 \ $ rather more helpful...  [Note that $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ are _not unique_.]

Comment: In any number of dimensions, two vectors are perpendicular if and only if their dot product vanishes. In three dimensions, two vectors are parallel if and only if their cross product is zero. I recommend reviewing the geometry behind dot products and cross products.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm not sure where I got cross-product from

Comment: RecklessReckoner7 - if they are not unique, is it possible to then find some parameters to define a and b? How would I do that?

Comment: You will have a relation between $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ , implying an infinite number of possible solutions.  (Various possible ways of expressing this have been shown in answers below.)

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Noting that the **dot product** (which is a scalar, not the **cross product**, which is a vector) of any two perpendicular vectors must be $0$ (thanks to Macavity's comment on the question), we can solve for $a$ and $b$ using the definition of the dot product.

First of all, we know that, by the definition of the dot product, the dot product of any two vectors $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ $= a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3$.

Here, substituting the respective values for $u_i$ and $v_i$ and simplifying the expression, we can find a "linear" equation representing all values for $a$ and $b$.

\begin{align}
u \cdot v &= u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + u_3v_3 \\
          &= 1 \cdot 2 + 2(1-b) + a \cdot 3 \\
          &= 2 + (2-2b) + 3a \\
          &= 4 - 2b + 3a
\end{align}

As we know that the dot product of two perpendicular vectors is $0$, we can substitute and solve:

\begin{align}
      0 &= 4 - 2b + 3a \\
2b - 3a &= 4 \quad && \text{In standard form} \\
      a &= \frac{2b - 4} 3 \quad && \text{Solving for $a$} \\
      b &= \frac{3a + 4} 3 \quad && \text{Solving for $b$}
\end{align}

Therefore, given any value of $a$ or $b$, we should be able to solve for the other.

Note that there are, however, **infinitely many solutions** to the problem for $a$ and $b$ -  essentially, the values are represented by a linear model where $a$ varies accordingly to $b$ (and vice versa). Below would be a graph that contains values of $a$ and $b$, graphed by WolframAlpha:

[image: Graph of $2b - 3a = 4$]

Comment: Great, thank you very much

Comment: No *problem*. (Although it actually *is* a *problem* asked on math.stackexchange.com... nevermind. ;p)

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write 
$$u \cdot v = |u| |v| \cos \theta$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$ (where $u,v$ are vectors).  So, if we want the vectors to be perpendicular, we want $\theta = \pi/2$ so that the RHS is zero.  In particular, two vectors are perpendicular if
$u \cdot v = 0$.
For $u = (1,2,a)$ and $v = (2,(1-b),3)$ we have
$$ u \cdot v = 2 + 2(1-b) + 3a$$
so that, setting this equal to zero,
$$4 - 2b + 3a = 0 \implies 3a -2b = -4$$
for them to be perpendicular.

Comment: I understand how you got that. Is it possible to find a and b?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are the numbers that satisfy the equation above: $3a- 2b = -4$.

Comment: Great, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Scalar not cross/Vector product has to be zero for orthogonal vectors. Therefore the values of a and b has to satisfy $$ 3a-2b+4= 0$$

Comment: So then is it possible for me to find a and b with only one equation?

Comment: you can't find a unique value for a and b. There are may values possible example a=2 and b=1, a=4 and b=2 etc. These values fall on a line.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me